# Dplyr Filtering Based on Year arithmetics

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data frame, where a snapshot of it looks like the following.

```
structure(list(cyear = c(1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1928, 1928, 1928, 1928, 1928), 
holdcyear = c(1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929), 
andiv = c(6.11, 7.19, 8.26, 7.88, 6.58, 5.26, 3.07, 2.87, 3.28, 4.87, 6.87, 5.97, 4.38, 5.74, 5.94, 5.52, 4.53, 5.05, 5.40, 5.51)), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to filter the data frame. As an example, I would like to filter a new data frame, so that I have all values where cyear is equal to some value, and holdcyear is equal to cyear + 1. The ending results should look like:

```
structure(list(cyear = c(1925, 1926, 1927, 1928), 
holdcyear = c(1926, 1927, 1928, 1929), 
andiv = c(7.19, 2.87, 5.74, 5.51)), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So, the filtering should happen when cyear is one year less than the holdcyear, the value of andiv would be saved for a new data frame.
I have tried to use various arithmetic functions in dplyr's filter function, but every time I end up with the wrong data frame. Could anybody provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(cyear == holdcyear - 1)
```

**Output**

```
  cyear holdcyear andiv
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1  1925      1926  7.19
2  1926      1927  2.87
3  1927      1928  5.74
4  1928      1929  5.51
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm not sure why it works with -1, but I didn't try that with my own code

Comment: :) ... it possibly works, because you defined that condition: "...filtering should happen when cyear is one year less than the holdcyear ..." :==> `cyear == holdcyear - 1`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(df1, cyear == (holdcyear - 1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not sure why it works with -1, albeit I get the right results now.

Answer (score 0):

Without dplyr.

```
df<- structure(list(cyear = c(1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1926, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1927, 1928, 1928, 1928, 1928, 1928), 
               holdcyear = c(1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929), 
               andiv = c(6.11, 7.19, 8.26, 7.88, 6.58, 5.26, 3.07, 2.87, 3.28, 4.87, 6.87, 5.97, 4.38, 5.74, 5.94, 5.52, 4.53, 5.05, 5.40, 5.51)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df[df$holdcyear-df$cyear == 1, ]
```